# I am trying to create react app .but I got error

Tags: reactjs

> `C:\Windows\System32>npx create-react-app my-app
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Windows\System32\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
>   react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> yarn add v1.22.0 [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching
>   packages... error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cac
>   he\v6\npm-levenary-1.1.1-842a9ee98d2075aa7faeedbe32679e9205f46f77-integrity\n
>   ode_modules\levenary\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected end of JSON
>   input". info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with
>   the information p rovided in
>   "C:\Windows\System32\my-app\yarn-error.log". info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this comm
>   and. info There appears to be trouble with your network connection.
>   Retrying... info There appears to be trouble with your network
>   connection. Retrying... info There appears to be trouble with your
>   network connection. Retrying... info There appears to be trouble with
>   your network connection. Retrying... info There appears to be trouble
>   with your network connection. Retrying... info There appears to be
>   trouble with your network connection. Retrying... info There appears
>   to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying... error
>   https://registry.yarnpkg.com/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.2.11.tgz:
>   ESOCKETTIMEDO UT
>
> Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom
>   react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Window s\System32\my-app has
>   failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting generated file...
>   yarn.lock Done.
>
> C:\Windows\System32>cd my-app
>
> C:\Windows\System32\my-app>npm start npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR!
>   syscall open npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\package.json npm ERR!
>   errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Windows\System32\pac kage.json' npm ERR! enoent This is related to
>   npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-02T10_07_42_
>   156Z-debug.log`

Comment: "There appears to be trouble with your network connection". If you can work out a way to manually download and install the required packages, that might work better

Comment: my network connection is ok

Answer (score 0):

Try with npx (npm 5.2+ and higher) : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

## Hello

Dear,
first, install node js and then npm and then try to restart your pc
after restart PC

```
npm install -g create-react
```

for better result restart more 1 time
and then

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I hope finally you success to install your app

Or more please visit this [Demo](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score -1):

first, install node js and then npm
and then try the command 
create-react-app my-app

Comment: I had installed node js and npm. I think errors related to the yarn package.

Comment: first, delete the package.json.lock file, then again install  npm install for the project directory and then yarn install command fire again